# How to rewrite php url to be more SEO friendly **without** using htaccess rewrite engine?

Tags: php, url-rewriting

Since I am not allow to use htaccess to rewrite the url (e.g. detail.php?id=1) to be more SEO friendly, I wonder if any alternative solution for my situation.

Is there any way to change

1. "example.com/detail.php?id=1" to "example.com/Potato/"
2. "example.com/detail.php?id=2" to "example.com/Banana/"
   And so on....?

   ```
   //using <href="detail.php?id=..."> to assign values to id
   <?php include_once(__DIR__ . "/left_nav.php"); ?>
       <?php
           if(isset($_GET['id'])) {
               switch ($_GET['id']) {
                   case 1:
                   case 2:
                   case 3:
                   case 4:
                   case 5:
                       echo $content[$_GET['id'] - 1];
                       $target_section = $_GET['id'] ;
                       break;
                   default:
                       echo $content[0];
                       $target_section = 1;
                       break;
               }
           }else{
               echo $content[0];
           }
       ?>
   ```

Comment: URL - SEO friendly is a pile of poo. Google does not cre about your url, it cares about the content of the site. Feel free to waist your time if you like (lots of people do)

Comment: That kind of rewriting *must* take place on the webserver.  If you can't use `.htaccess`, your only option may be to use your PHP code to generate static HTML pages at the URLs that you want to use.

Comment: without htaccess you have only one option to make your pages html with php.

Answer (score 0):

Without .htaccess each parameter of the url must be passed as a regular url query - IE. `someurl.com/index.php?param=value&key=value`.

You have two options. One is to pass a parameter like `some/var/passed/like/this` and split it up with php and use accordingly. The other is two simply make sure each slash corresponds to a file-path - IE `/some/var` corresponds to the file structure `/var/www/some/var`, or whatever.

This means you will always need to have file extensions like `.php` or `.html`, however, this might be more acceptable to you than passing many parameters via the url.